# Get json object for style React-Native

Tags: react-native

Just realized when I do the following code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({style: someobj})
```

styles doesn't actually contain that obj, but an int id that I believe references to the stylesheet.

```
console.log(styles) // outputs {style: #}
```

Is there a way for me to dynamically retrieve the style obj after creating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use StyleSheet.flatten method.[See StyleSheet doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/stylesheet.html#stylesheet)

```
StyleSheet.flatten(styles.stylId)
```

Answer (score 1):

buddy upstair is right, but not specific enough, I cant add a comment, so post an answer.

you should use flatten, like this:

`var someobj = {backgroundColor: 'red', fontSize: 12};
const styletest = StyleSheet.flatten({style: someobj});
console.log(styletest);`

Comment: yup thank you. had figured it out but this should help other people. I was using this with underscore for _.extend(style_obj, {new styles}) to dynamically update styles. For some reason though, _.extend(style_obj, {new styles}) this gives me the original style_obj, and I've had to do  _.extend({new styles}, style_obj).